# How does ChronicleMap handle concurrent reads and writes to same key?

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap, chronicle-map

We are exploring using ChronicleMap as a replacement of ConcurrentHashMap within a single JVM with persistence option.
Reading the [docs](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/blob/ea/docs/CM_Tutorial.adoc#single-chroniclemap-instance-per-jvm), it says  `Within the JVM environment, a ChronicleMap instance is a ConcurrentMap, and could be accessed concurrently the same way as, for example, a ConcurrentHashMap` .

I wanted to further understand, how concurrent reads/writes to same key is handled by ChronicleMap. Does it lock the segment containing the key, thereby allowing only 1 writer/multiple readers on the segment containing the key?

Comment: Following the thread!